# Unable to make sql server 2012 connection with android using eclipse

Tags: java, android, sql-server

#### I want to make connection of sql server-2012 with android using jtds in eclipse.But While launching it in eclipse by using mobile device instead of emulator and even on emulator it show me an error i.e; **Unable to get information from sql server:HNI-03-PC**.  
My server name = HNI-03-PC,instance=MSSQLSERVER,user=nikhil502,password=ocean502.
I write all this details in coonection string but it not open any connection. If I use this connection string in Normal java application it will give me fine result but in android giving error...Plz help me.  ERRORS are:

```
03-14 11:44:03.476: W/System.err(17039): java.sql.SQLException: Unable to get information from SQL Server: localhost.  
03-14 11:44:03.484: W/System.err(17039): at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.MSSqlServerInfo.<init>(MSSqlServerInfo.java:97)  
03-14 11:44:03.484: W/System.err(17039):at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC2.<init>(ConnectionJDBC2.java:276)  
03-14 11:44:03.484: W/System.err(17039):at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:187)
03-14 11:44:03.484: W/System.err(17039):at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:180)  
03-14 11:44:03.484: W/System.err(17039):at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:145)  
03-14 11:44:03.484: W/System.err(17039): at com.example.prejtds.MainActivity.query2(MainActivity.java:54)  
03-14 11:44:03.484: W/System.err(17039): at com.example.prejtds.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:33)  
03-14 11:44:03.484: W/System.err(17039):at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)  
03-14 11:44:03.484: W/System.err(17039):at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)  
03-14 11:44:03.492: W/System.err(17039):at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)  
03-14 11:44:03.492: W/System.err(17039):at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)  
03-14 11:44:03.492: W/System.err(17039):at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)  
03-14 11:44:03.492: W/System.err(17039):at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)  
03-14 11:44:03.492: W/System.err(17039):at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)  
03-14 11:44:03.492: W/System.err(17039):at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)  
03-14 11:44:03.492: W/System.err(17039): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)  
03-14 11:44:03.492: W/System.err(17039):at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)  
03-14 11:44:03.492: W/System.err(17039):at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I need some help like code....plz add this too..
I have put the following permission  in manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS"/>
```

and I also add **jtds1.2.5** in my project

I also **enabled TCP/IP,shared memory,named Pipes.**

```
package com.example.prejtds;
import net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DatabaseMetaData;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button show;

    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        show = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_show);

         show.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override

                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                    query2(); }
            });

    }

    @Override

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        return true;

    }

    public void query2()

    {

    Log.i("Android"," SQL Connect Example.");

   Connection conn = null;

    try {

    String driver = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";

    Class.forName(driver).newInstance();

    String connString 

="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/nikhil;encrypt=true;user=sa;instance=MSSQLSERVER";

    DriverManager.setLoginTimeout(20000);

    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connString);

    Log.w("Connection","open");

    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "connection estabilished",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

    ResultSet reset = stmt.executeQuery("select * from emp_details");

    while(reset.next()){    

        Log.w("Data:",reset.getString(3));

        Log.w("Data",reset.getString(2)); }

conn.close();

    }  catch(SQLException e){

        e.printStackTrace();

        //Log.w("Error connection","" + e.getMessage());


    } catch (Exception e)

    {

    Log.w("Error connection","" + e.getMessage());

    }

    }

}
```

I know how to make connectivity using mysql with php in android.
But for my project(in android) I need SQL SERVER-2012 so plz answer and also suggest me which db I will use if not getting answer using sql server and why ?

Thanx in advanced

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: unable to get information from sql server

Comment: I am triyng to run it on mobile device...and get an errors..

Comment: Will it run on emulator....

Comment: Update your question instead of writing comments please.

Comment: One thought that comes to mind is that it cannot see localhost because the app is a separate instance from the machine that localhost is running on. I am only able to connect to localhost when on a small LAN. But that's using a device. Not sure how AVDs handle this.